# How can I use i18n on different page with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

"expo": "^49.0.0"
"expo-localisation": "~14.3.0"
"i18n-js": "4.2.2" --> (current version gives error for "make-plural" library)

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/#other-translation-libraries

I installed the i18n library according to the instructions at the address above

I added the following code into my "_layout.tsx" file in the "app" folder and the "welcome" message works properly.

```
import { getLocales } from 'expo-localization';
import { I18n } from 'i18n-js';

const i18n = new I18n({
en: { welcome: 'Welcome' },
en: { welcome: 'Hello' },
});

i18n.locale = getLocales()[0].languageCode;
i18n.enableFallback = true;

console.log(i18n.t('welcome'));
```

But I don't know how to use it in my other subpages. For example, I add the following code to my "app -> (tabs) -> home -> main.tsx" file, but "TypeError: _i18nJs.I18n.t is not a function (it is undefined)" error.

```
import { I18n } from 'i18n-js'
<Text>{I18n.t('welcome')}</Text>
```

How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem

"app -> _layout.tsx"

```
import '../i18n.config';
```

I added it to the root directory -> i18n.config.ts

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import { getLocales } from 'expo-localization';
import en from "./language/en.json";
import tr from "./language/tr.json";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
    fullName: 'English'
  },
  tr: {
    translation: tr,
    fullName: 'Türkçe'
  }
};

const deviceLanguage = getLocales()[0].languageCode;

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
  resources,
  lng: deviceLanguage,
  fallbackLng: "en",
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

I added it where I will use it

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
const { t } = useTranslation();
<Text>{t("hello")}</Text>
```

worked that way for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use useTranslation:

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
...

const { t } = useTranslation();
...

<Text>{t('welcome')}</Text>
```

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import en from "./packs/en.json";
import it from "./packs/it.json";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
    fullName: 'English'
  },
  it: {
    translation: it,
    fullName: 'Italiano'
  }
};

const deviceLanguage = 'en';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
  resources,
  lng: deviceLanguage,
  fallbackLng: "en",
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

en.json

```js
{
"welcome": "Welcome"
}
```

it.json

```js
{
"welcome": "Benvenuto"
}
```

Also remember to bundle the i18n configuration by importing it in your root page

```
import i18n from "../language/i18n.config";
```

Comment: I tried a few hours ago, it did not give an error and did not translate. Can you send a working example in your hand.

Comment: @Yücel make sure to load the language packs, check my edit

Comment: i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
  resources,
  lng: deviceLanguage,
  fallbackLng: "en",
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed
  },
});

Did you include the file with this code anywhere. file name "i18n.config.tsx" ?

Comment: That code is from i18n.config.ts and it is used automatically by the useTranslation hook. Remember to add export default i18n; at the bottom of i18n.config.ts

Comment: error -> react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

Comment: What generates this error and did you init i18n by using i18n.use(initReactI18next)? Remember that you have to install react-i18next if you didnt yet

Comment: loaded

"i18next": "^23.10.1",
"react-i18next": "^14.1.0",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257184/discussion-between-jan-rezzonico-and-yucel).